# USING SELECT CASE based on a constant value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have this ff table called **equipment**:

```
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
| equip_id | chara_id | weapon_id | headgear_id | armor_id | ring_id |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
|        3 |        1 |         3 |           5 |        9 |       8 |
|        5 |        3 |         3 |           5 |        3 |       8 |
|        6 |        4 |         7 |           5 |        3 |       8 |
|        7 |        5 |         4 |           5 |        3 |       8 |
|        8 |        6 |         3 |           5 |        2 |       8 |
|       10 |        8 |         3 |           5 |        2 |       8 |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
```

and i have this long case statement:

```
switch ($equip->item_type) {
        case '1':
            # Weapon

            $sql_equip = "UPDATE equipment SET weapon_id = :item_id WHERE chara_id = :chara_id";  
            break;

        case '2':
            # Armor
            $sql_equip = "UPDATE equipment SET armor_id = :item_id WHERE chara_id = :chara_id";
            break;

        case '3':
            # Ring
            $sql_equip = "UPDATE equipment SET ring_id = :item_id WHERE chara_id = :chara_id";
            break;

        case '4':
            # Headgear
            $sql_equip = "UPDATE equipment SET headgear_id = :item_id WHERE chara_id = :chara_id";
            break;

        default:
            # do nothing...
            break;
    }
```

i saw some queries on the net that you can use case statements in you queries, ive searched the net and i cant seem to figure out a correct one to use.

i want it in 1 statement since i will wrap it on a transact function and will also add another line of mysql statement. so instead of doing 4x2(current) i will just do 2(if this could be done in 1 query) mysql queries.

Comment: @PeterLang it is already normalized.

Comment: You should think about changing your table model. Since you already work with item_type and item_id, why not create your table in that style? Your current model forces you to change the table and the code whenever a new item-type (shoes, second weapon, second ring) is added...

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Ok, changed my comment.

Comment: @PeterLang following your logic a simple users table have to be split into separate tables - username table, password table, email table etc. Just in case if we will need to add a pet dog name in the future. With current table setup a full armor set can be fetched in one one simple select. But with proposed one it would be a difficult task. Your setup is good for undetermined set of parameters. But for such a ting like armor set it is perfect to have it in one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have this statement,

```
UPDATE  equipment 
SET     weapon_id = CASE WHEN :itemtype = 1 THEN :item_id ELSE weapon_id END,
        armor_id = CASE WHEN :itemtype = 2 THEN :item_id ELSE armor_id END,
        ring_id = CASE WHEN :itemtype = 3 THEN :item_id ELSE ring_id END,
        headgear_id = CASE WHEN :itemtype = 4 THEN :item_id ELSE headgear_id END
WHERE   chara_id = :chara_id
```

but you need to pass three values, `:itemtype`, `:item_id`, `:chara_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
$fieldnames = array(1=>'weapon', 'armor', 'ring', 'headgear');
if (isset($fieldnames[$equip->item_type])) {
    $field = $fieldnames[$equip->item_type].'_id';
    $sql_equip = "UPDATE equipment SET $field = :item_id WHERE chara_id = :chara_id";
}
```

Comment: i shall look into this @home, but now ill go home :')